# Adding jQuery widget to Drupal page result in `$ is not a function`

Tags: jquery, drupal

I'm trying to add a datepicker widget to my form on Drupal.

I've a page with the following code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
</script>
<form action="/scripts/new-customer.php">
<div>Birth date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="bday" /></div>
</form>
```

But unfortunately I get the error in the subject. I tried to write as follows:

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

But I got the same error the line after.

Unfortunately, I cannot get any further with Drupal documentation.

Comment: use jQuery.conflict()

Comment: Have you include jQuery and jQuery UI library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of other JavaScript library conflict. use jQuery.noConflict()

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

jq(function() {
  jq( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

Before initialize

```
drupal_add_library('system','ui.datepicker')
```

Comment: Same error but with `jq` instead: `TypeError: jq(...).datepicker is not a function`.

Comment: have u include  jQuery UI library

Comment: drupal_add_library('system','ui.datepicker');

Comment: check the jquery ui datepicker included or not

Comment: Thank you very much. `drupal_add_library('system','ui.datepicker')` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but this might help:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is probably using [jQuery's noConflict option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).  Try `jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker()` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I get `TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid conflicts with other JS libraries "$" does not make scene in .js files globally.
So you should add following code surrounding js codes :

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.naturalessenceTheme = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

$('selector').mouseover(function() {
//now working
});

}
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Tamil, the following code is working very well:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="api/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js"></script>
<?php drupal_add_library('system','ui.datepicker') ?>
<script>
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq(function() {
        jq.datepicker.setDefaults(jq.datepicker.regional['it']);
        jq("#giornoSel").datepicker(
            { 
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
                altField: '#giorno', 
                altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
                showButtonPanel: true
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```